# State is only pushed to component when action is dispatched twice

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a simple array my store and a single action to add an item to this array if the value doesn't already exist.

The problem I'm experiencing is that my component subscription doesn't receive the updated state until the action is dispatched twice.

After that, it works as expected. My initial state is an empty array as expected, but I'm not understanding why the state isn't pushed when the action is dispatched, and the new state object is returned.

the reducer:

```js
export function addressFormsReducer(state = initialState, action: Action): AddressFormState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AddressFormActions.ZIP_CODE_LOOKUP_SUCCESS: {
      const zipCodeLookupResult = <IZipCodeLookupResult>action.payload;
      const index = _.findIndex(state, <IZipCodeLookupResult>{ formId: zipCodeLookupResult.formId });

      if (index >= 0) {
        state = [...state.slice(0, index), zipCodeLookupResult, ...state.slice(index + 1)];
      }
      else {
        state.push(zipCodeLookupResult);
      }

      return state;
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }

  }
}
```

the component subscription:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    ...

    this.sub = this.store.select<AddressFormState>('addressForms').subscribe(addressFormState => {
      let stateObj = addressFormState.filter(state => state.formId === 'ordering-provider')[0];
      if (stateObj) {
        this.zipCodeNotFound = stateObj.zipCodeNotFound;
      }
    });
  }
```

Why might that be happening?

Comment: you're mutating state. instead of `state.push(zipCodeLookupResult);` try `[...state, zipCodeLookupResult]`

Comment: @adharris You're absolutely correct. I have obviously been staring at this code for way too long. Please add an answer to that effect and I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely due to you mutating the state by calling `state.push`. Selecting from the store uses `distinctUntilChanged`, which uses object equality to detect if the state has changed.  For this reason, it's important to always treat the state as immutable. Try this instead:

```
if (index >= 0) {
    state = [...state.slice(0, index), zipCodeLookupResult, ...state.slice(index + 1)];
}
else {
    state = [...state, zipCodeLookupResult];
}
```